# Spring: Component session attribute name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to integrate Spring MVC in my existing web project.

Now I have a problem with the attribute name of session scoped components, which will be injected in Spring controllers:

```
@Autowired
private User user;
```

They always named 'scopedTarget.user' by default. But I like to use my own name 'user', because its already used in so many pages or classes.

Session Component:

```
@Component("user")
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long id;
private String name;

public User() {
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
}

}
```

JSP:

```
WISH: ${user} 
NOT: ${sessionScope['scopedTarget.user']}
```

Is there a possibility to change the name generator of session scoped components? 
I know it is possible for controller names.

Comment: You can add it to the model under the desired name or you can add 'staticAttributes' to the view resolver you use (if it is a url based one).

Comment: Thanks, but not so comfortable for me. I've thought there is a simple solution to change the name spring is using. Another possibility is perhaps to save it twice in session.

Comment: Have you looked at that property? You can name it whatever you want it is a `Map` taking key is the name, and you can reference the value.

Comment: Do you mean in my ViewResolver? No, but I will. If I have some JSP imports like <c:import url="/blahblah.jsp"/> it will not work in these pages, right?